# Mapping over array of objects returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in React app I'm trying to increment +1 to the id field of each object in the array.

```
function App() {
  const[todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Take out the trash',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Dinner',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Meeting with boss',
      completed: false
    }
  ]);

  function onClick(){
    setTodos(todos => todos.map(todo => todo.id = todo.id + 1))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="todo-list">
        <ul>
          {todos.map(todo => <li>{todo.id},{todo.title},{String(todo.completed)}</li>)}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={()=>onClick()}
        >Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the initial rendering of the page list of objects is displayed properly. On first click of the button they change to this:

```
,,undefined
,,undefined
,,undefined
```

On 3rd click to this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'id' on number '2'
```

did I miss something about the map function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function onClick(){
  setTodos(todos => todos.map(todo => todo.id = todo.id + 1))
 }
```

You're returning the `todo.id` from your map function, therefore you're setting todos as an array of ids `[2, 3, 4]`. Then when you try to access `todo.id`, it is `undefined` as `number.id` is undefined`.

You're also mutating state by saying `todo.id = ...`. If you find yourself using the assignment oprerator (`=`) when setting state, you may be doing something wrong. You should never have `state = ...`.

You want to do something like this:

```
function onClick(){
  setTodos(prev => prev.map(t => ({ ...t, id: t.id + 1 })))
 }
```

I've also renamed `todos` to `prev` as you're creating a shadowed variable name.

Comment: I think return statement is compulsory when you put block there.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanKhan but there's no blocks used. It's just an inlined Object literal.

Comment: How did TypeError occur then?

Comment: @MuhammadHassanKhan If you're referring to _"You're not returning anything from your map function"_, then you're right, the return is **implicit**.

Comment: I've updated *You're not returning anything* to *You're returning the `todo.id`* as the return is implicit as Muhammad pointed out.

Comment: Cool, now I've learned that todo that is being currently iterated over by map is there to just reference it, but wont actually be added to the new array. Gotta create new whole object that i want to be added to new array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't return new todo entity in there, but just return `id` property, that's is a bug. Here's is a fix:

```
  function onClick(){
    setTodos(todos => todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, id: todo.id + 1 })))
  }
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Map function iterate to each value and return the mapped value you computed in the iterator.

Your code converts array of todo objects to array of incremented todo ids like `[2,3,4]` so when next your map method runs it gives the error you are facing. As first time your map has converted objects to integers.

You should update your map method something like this: `todos.map(todo => ({...todo, id: todo.id + 1}))`

**Note:** Also you don’t need to write `todos =>` in your setTodos hook.

Comment: Nope, see the error carribean posted i.e TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` function not return a object but I think you should use the `reduce` JavaScript function

```
function onClick() {
    const reducerFunction = (r, v) => r.concat({ ...v, id: v.id + 1 })
    setTodos(
      todos.reduce(reducerFunction, [])
    );
}
```

I also think you should try the [useReduce](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) Hooks, in this case generate solutions more clean.

> An alternative to useState. Accepts a reducer of type (state, action)
>   => newState, and returns the current state paired with a dispatch method. (If you’re familiar with Redux, you already know how this
>   works.)
>
> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
>   state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
>   depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize
>   performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can
>   pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.